# Defining new environment for align

Tags: align, environments

```
\NewEnviron{myequation}{%
\begin{align*}
\scalebox{1.5}{$\BODY$}
\end{align*}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myequation}
        y = mx+c
    \end{myequation}   
\end{document}
```

The above code works fine. **But after I add intertext in the align it shows me error.**

```
\NewEnviron{myequation}{%
\begin{align*}
\scalebox{1.5}{$\BODY$}
\end{align*}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myequation}
        y = mx+c
        \intertext{Equation of straight line}
    \end{myequation}   
\end{document}
```

I need to add intertext and also scale up the size of the equations. What can I do?

Comment: the use of align here is doing nothing useful at all, you are putting the whole content into  inline `$` math in `\scalebox` so there can not be any alignment and can only be one line. Scaling mathematics should be avoided in any case.  why not simply use `\large\begin{align*}...` if you need larger text.

Comment: @David Carlisle Ok. I never thought of that. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any way to only make the equations to have larger size but not the intertext?

Comment: easiest to start the intertext with \normalsize